# Aggregate two proportions from subpopulations to estimate population proportion

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, descriptive-statistics, standard-error, proportion

Assume there is a population of 2000 individuals, of which 1200 are male and 800 are female.

Assume samples have been drawn from the male and female subpopulations separately to compute a proportion of a characterisic of interest, yielding the following:

| Population | Population size | Sample size | sample proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 1200 | 200 | 0.2 |
| Female | 800 | 200 | 0.6 |

Where the standard error/confidence intervals for the estimated proportions for each subpopulation can be estimated in the standard way.

I believe I can generate a point estimate for the proportion of the characteristic of interest in the whole population from this data by calculating:

$$
1200/2000 * 0.2 + 800/2000 * 0.6 = 0.36
$$

i.e., the weighted average of the sub-population proportion estimates by the subpopulation prevalence in the whole population.

How can I calculate a confidence interval for the global proportion? My intuition would be to calculate the standard error for the two subpopulations and basically weight it in the same way, and then use it to calculate the confidence interval for the global proportion. Is this approach correct?

Comment: You will find it simpler to estimate the *total number* of people with the characteristic of interest, rather than its proportion.  Then combining the subpopulation-based estimates is a simple matter of adding them and, as usual, the standard error of a sum is computed as the root mean square.  There will be problematic situations where the subsample proportions are extreme and in opposite directions: those situations call into question the meaning of the entire exercise and perhaps require special treatment and interpretation.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment though I'm not sure I follow :) So in the example above, would you suggest to use the subpopulation estimates of the proportion to calculate the expected number of people in that subpop with the characteristic (basically just multiply the point estimate of precision by the population size), and then just add these to calculate the total number of people with the characteristic in the population? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That's correct.  The import of my suggestion is that it also indicates the correct manner of combining their standard errors.

Comment: @whuber thank you, then what you suggest is: (1) estimate the total number of obs with the characteristic for the two subpops (call it $T_x$ for $x\in\{1,2\}$ denoting the subpops), (2) calculate the standard error $SE_x$ for $T_x$, (3) calculate the point estimate for the whole population as $T_1 + T_2$, (4) calculate the standard error of the sum as $\sqrt{SE_1^2 + SE_2^2}$(5) to calculate $SE_x$ above i suppose i can just multiply the standard error of the proportion for $x$ by the population size? Am I on the right track?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: @whuber "about right" or "right right" :D if you have the time, could you elaborate on what you mean above with the problematic situations? You mean cases where the subsample proportions are very different (e.g. very small vs very large)?